Why Do Two Similar Code Snippets Yield Different Results for Symbolic Equations?
I am calculating (what seems to me) the same thing in two ways but am getting different results. I'd appreciate any help in understanding the reason behind this.
I have a list of symbolic equations, each defined as:
a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + ... + a30 * x30 = b
eqs=[]  # expressions
reps={} # values of symbols in the expressions
b=[] # numeric value that the known expression has
for i,e in enumerate(eqs):
    A = (e-b[i]).subs(reps)
    B = e.subs(reps)-b[i]
    if A != B:
        print (A, B)

These are giving different results for A and B:


I don't think anyone can answer with what is shown here. For one thing you are asking about the difference from two identical pieces of code. Distil your problem down to something small enough that you can show complete code.

Related, if not identical, question, deleted by the author recently. You'll need >= 10k reputation to see it.

Maybe just a floating point issue: a=sum([1./3]*12);b=sum([1./3]*3);c=5;d=sum([1./3]*15)->a+b-c==0 but d-c != 0 and a+b!=d.

I notice the (magnitude of the) errors get progressively worse over the iteration. This suggests either there is some sort of creep, and the iterations of the loop have some sort of side effect; or there's a theme to the order of the equations. Try reversing the loop, or find the theme and you may find the cause.

The only reason these should be different is if you are substituting floating point values. And then the reason will likely be just the order in which SymPy process arguments. The best way to evaluate a symbolic expression with a dictionary of values is expr.evalf(subs=values), e.g. trivial case x.evalf(subs={x:1})->1.0. Doing it this way will keep increasing precision to (try) make sure you get a meaningful and accurate result.
Experiments to try

apply nsimplify(v, rational=True) to each float and compare the two methods. They should give the same results either way because Rational computations are exact (and slower) than those obtained from floats

in method one substitute in floats to compute the lhs and then do (lhs - b).evalf(subs={b: bval}) to see if you get the same thing as method tow with expr.evalf(subs=dict_of_all_values)


Data that would clearly demonstrate the issue is needed to make progress on this issue: just fill in the the details of the edited OP.
